# How to get all "Columns" from Parse platform "Table" using distinct, like GROUP BY on SQL

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse with Postgres, and I need to retrieve some lines from a table.

I need to group by one column, just like the `GROUP BY` in SQL, but when I use the `distinct` or `aggregate` on my queries, both just return the column that I'm using as parameter, not all columns.

### Example

My table

```sql
Product | Category | Price
--------+----------+------
Apple   | Fruit    |     5
Orange  | Fruit    |     3
Rice    | Cereal   |     8
Grape   | Fruit    |     6
```

Then, I run the query:

```js
query.distinct('Category').then(....
```

Which results in:

```js
["Fruit", "Cereal"]
```

But I want something like:

```js
[
  {Product: Apple, Category: Fruit, Price:5},
  {Product: Rice, Category: Cereal, Price:8}
]
```

As I said, just like the `GROUP BY` via SQL.

It's that possible?

Currently I'm using one query with the `.distinct()` and the results of that query as parameter in a `.containedIn()`, but I think that it must be a better way of doing this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [aggregate](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate) to achieve what you're looking for in a single query:

```js
await Promise.all([
  new Parse.Object('MyTable').save({ Product: 'Apple', Category: 'Fruit', 'Price': 5 }),
  new Parse.Object('MyTable').save({ Product: 'Orange', Category: 'Fruit', 'Price': 3 }),
  new Parse.Object('MyTable').save({ Product: 'Rice', Category: 'Cereal', 'Price': 8 }),
  new Parse.Object('MyTable').save({ Product: 'Grape', Category: 'Fruit', 'Price': 6 }),
]);

const pipeline = [{
  group: {
    objectId: '$Category',
    first: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
  },
},
{
  project: {
    objectId: false,
    Product: "$first.Product",
    Category: "$first.Category",
    Price: "$first.Price",
  },
}];


const result = await new Parse.Query('MyTable')
  .aggregate(pipeline);

console.log(result);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
[ { Product: 'Rice', Category: 'Cereal', Price: 8 },
  { Product: 'Grape', Category: 'Fruit', Price: 6 } ]
```

See:

- [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)
- [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)

If you want to specify the order, you can add a sort stage to your pipeline.

If you want to understand what is going on, remove the `project` stage and you'll see the raw output of the `group` stage.

Comment: I tried your solution without success, maybe it only works with mongo, and as I said, we are using Postgres

Comment: ugh.  I didn't catch the postgress bit there.  Aggregates can be done with Postgres.  obviously it won't be exactly the same as $first and $$ROOT are mongo specific, there may be a way to do by an aggregate pipeline that is similar to how I did for mongo.  Good luck.

Comment: @DkRibeiro it should also work with Postgres. Do you mind to open an issue to the GitHub repo so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to incorporate this into Parse, but once you have your data, you can run it through the following function to get your desired data.

```js
function groupBy(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    if (groups[item[key]] === undefined) {
      groups[item[key]] = item; // Only store the first one that matches
    }
    return groups;
  }, {});
}
```

There are three different ways to group.

1. `groupBy` – Your desired result
2. `groupByCount` – Count of items that in each category
3. `groupByAll` – All items, grouped by their category

```js
let csvData = `
  Product,Category,Price
  Apple,Fruit,5
  Orange,Fruit,3
  Rice,Cereal,8
  Grape,Fruit,6
`;
let jsonData = csvToJson(csvData, true);

console.log(groupBy(jsonData, 'Category'));
console.log(groupByCount(jsonData, 'Category'));
console.log(groupByAll(jsonData, 'Category'));

function groupBy(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    if (groups[item[key]] === undefined) {
      groups[item[key]] = item;
    }
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

function groupByCount(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    groups[item[key]] = (groups[item[key]] || 0) + 1;
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

function groupByAll(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    groups[item[key]] = (groups[item[key]] || []).concat(item);
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

function csvToJson(csv, headersIncl) {
  return (lines => {
    return (headersIncl ? lines.slice(1) : lines).map((line) => {
      return lines[0].reduce((obj, key, i) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, {
          [headersIncl ? key : i]: line[i]
        });
      }, {});
    });
  })(csv.trim().split('\n').map(line => line.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/g)));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: We tried this, but we have a large volume of data, so this isn't a good solution...